# PDOStatement $statement execute http 500 error

Tags: php, mysql

My PDOStatement $statement produce HTTP 500 and i don't know why! Here is my code:

```
final class ContatoDao {

private $db = null;

public function __destruct() {
    //Fecha a conexão
    $this->db = null;
}

private function getDb() {
    if ($this->db !== null) {
        return $this->db;
    }
    $config = Config::getConfig("db");
    try {
        $this->db = new PDO($config['dsn'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw new Exception('Conexao com o banco de dados falhou: ' . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    return $this->db;
}

private function execute($sql, Contato $contato) {
    $statement = $this->getDb()->prepare($sql);
    $this->executeStatement($statement, $this->getParams($contato));
    if (!$contato->getId()) {
        return $this->findById($this->getDb()->lastInsertId());
    }
    if (!$statement->rowCount()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Contato with ID "' . $contato->getId() . '" não existe.');
    }
    return $contato;
}

private function executeStatement(PDOStatement $statement, array $params) {
    if (!$statement->execute($params)) {
        self::throwDbError($this->getDb()->errorInfo());
    }
}

private function query($sql) {
    $statement = $this->getDb()->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($statement === false) {
        self::throwDbError($this->getDb()->errorInfo());
    }
    return $statement;
}

/**
 * Recebe id para efetuar a busca 
 * @param type $id 
 * @return retorna o objeto \Contato
 */
public function findById($id) {
    $row = $this->query('SELECT * FROM contatos WHERE deleted = 0 and id = ' . (int) $id)->fetch();
    if (!$row) {
        return null;
    }
    $contato = new Contato();
    ContatoMapper::map($contato, $row);
    return $contato;
}

/**
 * Salva o objeto Contato na base de dados.
 * @param Contato $contato
 * @return type
 */
private function insert(Contato $contato) {
    $contato->setDeletado(false);
    $sql = '
        INSERT INTO contatos (id, nome, email, msg, phone, deletado)
            VALUES (:id, :nome, :email, :msg, :phone, :deletado)';
    return $this->execute($sql, $contato);
}

/**
 * Efetua atualização.
 * @param Contato $contato para fazer atualização.
 * @return type void
 */
private function update(Contato $contato) {

    $sql = '
        UPDATE contatos SET
            nome = :nome,
            email = :email,
            msg = :msg,
            phone = :phone,
            deletado = :deletado,
        WHERE
            id = :id';
    return $this->execute($sql, $contato);
}

/**
 * function para salvar Contato $contato base de dados
 * @param function recebe Contato $contato.
 * @return type void
 */
public function save(Contato $contato) {
    if ($contato->getId() === null) {
        return $this->insert($contato);
    }
    return $this->update($contato);
}

private function getParams(Contato $contato) {
    $params = array(
        ':id' => $contato->getId(),
        ':nome' => $contato->getNome(),
        ':email' => $contato->getEmail(),
        ':msg' => $contato->getMensagem(),
        ':phone' => $contato->getPhone(),
        ':deletado' => $contato->getDeletado(),
    );
    return $params;
}

private static function throwDbError(array $errorInfo) {
    // TODO log error, send email, etc.
    throw new Exception('DB error [' . $errorInfo[0] . ', ' . $errorInfo[1] . ']: ' . $errorInfo[2]);
}
}
```

I'm trying save the object Contato in Mysql and it Works but after that the error http 500 show up

if you want to see the error just go [To see the error](http://indexacao.esy.es/web/index.php?page=contact)

Through this code below i call the method to save the object in my little Project and i will put the try/catch.

```
  <?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
$errors = array();
$contato = new Contato();

if (array_key_exists('cancel', $_POST)) {
    Utils::redirect('home');
} elseif (array_key_exists('save', $_POST)) {

    $data = array(
        'nome' => $_POST['contato']['nome'],
        'email' => $_POST['contato']['email'],
        'msg' => $_POST['contato']['msg'],
        'phone' => $_POST['contato']['phone'],
    );

    ContatoMapper::map($contato, $data);

    $errors = ContatoValidator::validade($contato);

    if (empty($errors)) {
        Utils::sendEmail($contato);

        $contatoDao = new ContatoDao();
        $contato = $contatoDao->save($contato);

        Utils::redirect('home');
    } else {
        echo $errors;        
    }
 }
```

And this is my config class that i use to retrieve information to connect MySQL

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

final class Config {

    /** @var array config data */
    private static $data = null;


    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function getConfig($section = null) {
        if ($section === null) {
            return self::getData();
        }
        $data = self::getData();
        if (!array_key_exists($section, $data)) {
            throw new Exception('Unknown config section: ' . $section);
        }
        return $data[$section];
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    private static function getData() {
        if (self::$data !== null) {
            return self::$data;
        }
        self::$data = parse_ini_file('../config/config.ini', true);
        return self::$data;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is just a class. How you call for it's methods?

Comment: No idea how you connect, **that would be useful**! PDO generates `PDOException` and not `Exception` catching **that would be useful**! `prepare` and `execute` generate PDOException also but you are not `try/catch`ing anything in those methods either, **that would be useful**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RiggsFolly thanks for your help and attention to my problem and u_mulder.

I just alter the method execute and put the try/catch as you suggest and bingo. Now is working !!!!

```
private function execute($sql, Contato $contato) {
    $statement = $this->getDb()->prepare($sql);
    $this->executeStatement($statement, $this->getParams($contato));
    if (!$contato->getId()) {
        return $this->findById($this->getDb()->lastInsertId());
    }
    if (!$statement->rowCount()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Contato with ID "' . $contato->getId() . '" não existe.');
    }
    return $contato;
}
```

After modification:

```
private function execute($sql, Contato $contato) {
    try {
        $statement = $this->getDb()->prepare($sql);
        $this->executeStatement($statement, $this->getParams($contato));
        if (!$contato->getId()) {
            return $this->findById($this->getDb()->lastInsertId());
        }
        if (!$statement->rowCount()) {
            throw new NotFoundException('Contato with ID "' . $contato->getId() . '" não existe.');
        }            
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getTraceAsString();
    }
    return $contato;
}
```